# 18.04 Install Problem: KeyError: 'MAJOR' / Subiquity

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

Trying to install 18.04 on a SuperMicro box and getting errors that stop the process.

Seems to have something to do with subiquity but not sure what the problem is.

[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device `dev-disk-by\x2duuid`...
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for `/subiquity_config`.

Tracepack (most recent call last):

> File "/snap/subiquity/620/usr/bin/subiquity", line 11, in 
> load_entry_point('subiquity==0.0.5', 'console_scripts', 'subiquity-tui')()
>
> ...
>
> KeyError: 'MAJOR'

[image: Screen capture of install error]

Comment: Seems to be a problem with NVMe support on this system and 18.04 - I tried .2 & .3.

1. When I removed the NVMe drives the installation proceeds.
2. When I move the NVMe drives to different slots installation stops.
3. When I go back to 16.04 with NVMe drives in place installation proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

Vendor confirms it is a driver issue with 18.04.

Chassis Model: X10DSC+

NVMe Model: PM1725A, 800 GB, NVMe PCIe3.0